# shell script to read specific content of all file and write to a news file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a files in parent directory which have a extension *sac, these file contain earthquake wave form header information. I want to print the specific header information of all files in a one file one below other. 
Here what i did so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=map
for i in ./*sac

do

SLA=`saclhdr -STLA $i`

SLO=`saclhdr -STLO $i`

ELA=`saclhdr -EVLA $i`

ELO=`saclhdr -EVLO $i`

echo "MAP GREAT CIRCLE RAY PATHS USING PROJECT">file ; 

echo "$SLA $SLO " >>file;

echo "$ELA $ELO " >>file;

echo "PLOT EPICENTER LOCATIONS" >>$file;

echo "$ELA $ELO " >>file;

echo "PLOT STATION LOCATIONS">>$file ;

echo "$SLA $SLO " >>file;

done
```

The output is:

```
MAP GREAT CIRCLE RAY PATHS USING PROJECT

-10.4807 105.652 

-7.7592 67.8257 

PLOT EPICENTER LOCATIONS

-7.7592 67.8257 

PLOT STATION LOCATIONS

-10.4807 105.652
```

Here I am getting printed information of one file I want print all files  specified content

```
SLA SLO

ELA ELO
```

one by one of all files

Comment: Please show us sample Input_file once.

Comment: Let's say you had two input files, how should the output look like?

Comment: Can you specify the desired output for two sample files? @rehman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=map
echo "MAP GREAT CIRCLE RAY PATHS USING PROJECT" > "$file"
for i in ./*sac
do
  SLA=$(saclhdr -STLA "$i")
  SLO=$(saclhdr -STLO "$i")
  ELA=$(saclhdr -EVLA "$i")
  ELO=$(saclhdr -EVLO "$i")
  echo "$SLA $SLO "
  echo "$ELA $ELO "
done >> "$file"
```

The redirection has to be placed beyond the for loop body in order to append continuously to the file and not recreate it on each turn.

Comment: Its ok but I have to add more lines like

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line.

```
echo "MAP GREAT CIRCLE RAY PATHS USING PROJECT">file ;
```

you are overwriting the contents. use >> instead of >